# WIA 2.0 - IWiaDevMgr2::GetImgDlg() - How to declare/init the ppbstrFilePaths parameter

Tags: c++, wia, bstr, double-pointer

I'm trying to implement some WIA 2.0 code in my VS2012 C++ library and have run into a problem with the **IWiaDevMgr2::GetImageDlg** call, specifically the ppbstrFilePaths paraneter.  I'm not quite sure how to declare/initialize it.

From the documentation at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa359932(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa359932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ppbstrFilePaths [in] TYPE - BSTR**
>
> The address of a pointer to an array of paths for the scanned files. Initialize the pointer to point to an array of size zero (0) before IWiaDevMgr2::GetImageDlg is called. See Remarks.

I've tried all sorts of variations on declaring this with no success, for example:

```
    // No scanner selection dialog, hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY
    BSTR *files = new BSTR[0];
    HRESULT hr = _pWiaDevMgr->GetImageDlg(0, NULL, *_parentHwnd, path, fileTemplate, numFiles, &files, &_pWiaItemRoot);
```

I've also tried things similar to this:

```
    // No scanner selection dialog, hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY
    BSTR **files = (BSTR**)CoTaskMemAlloc(0);
    *files = new BSTR[0];
    HRESULT hr = _pWiaDevMgr->GetImageDlg(0, NULL, *_parentHwnd, path, fileTemplate, &numFiles, files, &_pWiaItemRoot);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for declaring and initializing this BSTR**?  I'm not a big C++ dev and pretty much guessing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was on the right track with my first try:

```
CComBSTR path("D:\\TestWiaScan");
CComBSTR fileTemplate("FileName");
LONG numFiles = 0L;

BSTR *files = new BSTR[0];
HRESULT hr1 = _pWiaDevMgr->GetImageDlg(0, NULL, _parentHwnd, path, fileTemplate, &numFiles, &files, &_pWiaItemRoot);
if (files)
{
    for(int i=0;i < numFiles;i++)
    {
        SysFreeString(files[i]);
    }
}
CoTaskMemFree(files);

if (_pWiaItemRoot)
{
    _pWiaItemRoot->Release();
    _pWiaItemRoot = NULL;
}
```

The reason my first try wasn't working was because of issues with the BSTR parameters I was passing in.  Using CComBSTR or SysAllocString resolved that.